# Applications of physics beyond QFT

Tags: applied-physics

Are there any applied results (inventions) based on physics beyond quantum field theory? By beyond QFT I mean any physical theory that is (maybe slightly) different from classical physics, relativity, quantum physics and quantum field theories.
By applied results I mean not-only-on-paper results.

Comment: Is there anything after QFT that's been experimentally verified in the first place? If you're okay with *effective* descriptions (e.g. string theory giving a useful description of condensed matter phenomena, despite not being literal) then you'll probably have better luck.

Comment: Suggestion to the title (v2): Change the word _after QFT_ into _beyond QFT,_ and the word _application_ into _experimental evidence._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by results you mean only inventions, the answer is, to my knowledge, no, since how could we engineer something we don't know anything about? Unfortunately we are not anymore at the times where inventors could build things without really knowing the underlying physics.

If you accept Topological field theories as 'beyond',which are widely used in condensed matter, then yes. They are actually trying to build quantum processors using anyons, so you can consider this as an invention.

A group of theoretical physicists at NASA is trying to build a warp engine using (almost)-beyond-GR. Not invented though! (yet?)

Comment: All of theories you mention agree with experiments?
And can you point out clearly how are they different from QFTs?

Comment: Broadly speaking a TFTs (topological field theories) differ from QFTs because while the point of the latter is to calculate expectation values/n-point functions etc ,the former is used to compute topological invariants. For what concerns its experimental realisation you have plenty of experimental results agreeing with the theory, especially in condensed matter systems (Dirac Points in graphene, Anderson localisation, spin liquids, quantum hall...)

Comment: I really couldn't say about GR: surely what they are doing at NASA is beyond-textbooks level; unfortunately this one has not seen any experimental realisation yet even though they are designing the first experiments.