# Applications of gravitational waves

Tags: gravitational-waves, applied-physics

**What are the technological/engineering applications currently being explored that make use of gravitational waves?** I realize this can be broad and opinionated, so I want to emphasize narrowing the question down to *current, tangible explorations* or at least *substantial speculations with solid basis*, and *not* purely fanciful speculations as interesting as sci.fi. may be.

I ask this as a scientist but one with no expertise in physics aside from a popular science interest in it, and considering how the growth in our familiarity with the fundamental force of electromagnetism led to very significant technological advances. I'm not sure how analogous our technological advancements with electromagnetism are however, as gravitational waves are a fundamentally different force (pun intended) and appear so far to be very, very minuscule compared to the events which generate them.

---

This question is related to [What are the benefits of Gravitational wave studies?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/229243/what-are-the-benefits-of-gravitational-wave-studies?rq=1) but I'm asking more specifically what, if any, applications are currently being explored. I recognize actual gravitational wave interactions are relatively new to us, so we may be blind to future implications as @AccidentalFourierTransform on that question mentioned was the case with EM progress:

> Why did scientists spend time and money on studying EM waves right after Maxwell theory? Just to test the theory? Or with some economical/practical benefit in mind? Well, I like to think they did because of scientific curiosity and love for the natural philosophy. They might have had practical intentions, but they could never expect that some day, every aspect of our life would depend on EM waves. How can we know what will be the applications of G waves?

This is also a similar question to [Applications of physics beyond QFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123813/applications-of-physics-beyond-qft?rq=1) but I am specifically interested in gravitational waves in general, not quantum physics theory.

Comment: If I understand right, you are asking about better mousetraps, but not  gravitational wave astronomy?

Comment: Gravitational wave astronomy is certainly a technological/engineering application. It's the only one I'm aware of. Better mousetraps are hard to envision. Apparently the question is deemed too broad, but the answer @ViktorToth already provided is a good "none for now" answer as well.

Comment: It's probably just too soon to ask.  Electromagnetism is an easier engineering challenge, and even there it took 25 years to get from Maxwell's equations to Hertz's demonstration of electromagnetic signal transmission and another 15 years to get Marconi's wireless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no foreseeable applications of gravitational waves.

The gravitational waves that were detected last year... granted, they were produced quite a distance away, but their production required two roughly 30 solar mass black holes to coalesce, converting roughly 3 solar masses worth of mass into gravitational wave energy, producing gravitational waves at a power level that, at its peak, briefly outshone *all the electromagnetic radiation from the entire visible universe*.

And that, we were able to detect, just barely, with two gigantic detectors that were situated half a continent apart.

Electromagnetic waves were used widely long before Maxwell's theory, e.g., in the form of visible light (even if it was not recognized before Maxwell that these are, in fact, electromagnetic waves). But the specific predictions of Maxwell's theory, which allowed electromagnetic waves to be produced directly using electric and/or magnetic equipment, were indeed tested initially just to validate the theory. Here is a quote from Heinrich Hertz, who conducted the first such experiment, a quarter century after Maxwell's prediction: "*It's of no use whatsoever* [...] *this is just an experiment that proves Maestro Maxwell was right—we just have these mysterious electromagnetic waves that we cannot see with the naked eye. But they are there.*"